# Delete multiple occurrences of the same ID # and code in a junction table

Tags: sql, t-sql

`enter code here`[image]

My problem is this: in this database the junction table contains some rows where the kha_id and the icd_fk are the same.  While it's OK that kha_id appears in icd_junction more than once , it has to be with a separate icd_fk.  I can run a query and get all of the ID#s and the codes which are listed more than once, but is there an industry-standard way of going about deleting all but one occurrence of each?

example: what i have is above

```
KHA_ID: 123456  V23 
        123456  V23
        123456  V24

I need one of the rows kha_id=123456 and ICD_FK=V23 taken out.
```

Comment: Check Constraint? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

Comment: Industry standard would be to not have a spurious `ID` column in `ICD_Junction` when `KHA_ID` and `ICD_FK` would together form a perfect primary key for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
DELETE j1
  FROM ICD_Junction AS j1
 WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM ICD_Junction AS j2
           WHERE j2.KHA_ID = j1.KHA_ID
             AND j2.ICD_FK = j1.ICD_FK
             AND j2.ID < j1.ID
        )
;
```

will delete, for each `KHA_ID` and `ICD_FK`, all but one relevant row of `ICD_Junction`. (Specifically, it will keep the one with the least `ID`, and delete the rest.)

Once you've run the above, you should fix whatever code caused the duplication, and add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) to prevent this from happening again.

*(Disclaimer: Not tested, and it's been a while since I last used SQL Server.)*

---

**Edited to add:** If I'm understanding your comment correctly, you also need help with the query to find duplicates? For that, you can write:

```
SELECT KHA_ID,
       ICD_FK,
       COUNT(1)          -- the number of duplicates
  FROM ICD_Junction
 GROUP
    BY KHA_ID,
       ICD_FK
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
;
```

Comment: The duplication was caused for billing purposes and isn't incorrect. For research purposes, I only need to know if it was there or not :) Thanks :)

Comment: For it to keep the the least I think it should be j2.ID >  still +1

Comment: @wootscootinboogie You comment is not consistent with the problem statement  "it has to be with a separate icd_fk"

Comment: @Blam: No, because the goal is to delete from `j1` whenever there's a `j2` with a lesser `ID`.

Comment: You answer reads KEEP the one with the least ID.  If I am missing something then sorry.   If it deletes from j1 when there is a j2 with a lesser value then will it not delete the larger?

Comment: @Blam: Yes, exactly. It will keep the one with the least ID, by deleting the ones with larger IDs. (Or am I misunderstanding your question?)

Comment: @Blam: Are you sure about that? [This doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) seems to disagree with you.

Comment: I said I tested.  Did you?  I used SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: @Blam: You're right, sorry, you did say you'd tested; and now I've tested as well, just to satisfy my curiosity, and I got the same result. I don't understand *why* `DELETE [FROM] table_name` and `DELETE table_name FROM table_name [[AS] t]` and `DELETE t FROM table_name [AS] t` are all allowed, but `DELETE [FROM] table_name [AS] t` is not; but I suppose it's not our place to question Microsoft. :-P Anyway, thank you for the information, I'll update my answer!

Comment: You could give me a +1 I did for you

Comment: If you need to act on an alias then you must specify and that behavior is different from SQL 2005 and prior and not reflected in the documentation.  If you delete from a self join (an option here) it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The original question was delete but the comment was find

```
       Select jDup.*
       FROM ICD_Junction AS j
       JOIN ICD_Junction AS jDup
       On  j.KHA_ID = jDup.KHA_ID
       AND j.ICD_FK = jDup.ICD_FK
       AND j.ID < jDup.ID

       Select max(jDup.ID), min(jDup.ID), count(*), jDup.KHA_ID, jDup.ICD_FK
       FROM  ICD_Junction AS jDup
       Group By jDup.KHA_ID, jDup.ICD_FK 
       Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Note that that can give *way* too many results; for example, if a certain `(KHA_ID, ICD_FK)` combination appears ten times, then your query will return forty-five (9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1) rows for that combination.

Answer (score 0):

You want something that uses ROW_NUMBER() and partition by.  The reason is that it will let you pick one row to keep from a table that doesn't have a unique id.  Like if this was a pure intersection table with no identity, you could use a variation on this to delete all rows where RowID > 1, leaving you just the unique rows.  And it works just as well when you do have a unique id, where you can choose to preserve the earliest id.

```
select * from  (select KHA_ID, ICD_FK, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY KHA_ID, ICD_FK
             ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowID
    from ICD_Junction ) ordered where RowID > 1
```